# <!--[if lte IE8]>< ![endif]--> appearing on site and dropdown issue

Tags: php, html, css

My url: http://bitly.com/Pa3xJS

Issue #1: In IE, `<!--[if lte IE8]>< ![endif]-->` appears on the site? This should be correct markup, why is it appearing?

Issue #2: In IE, when you hover over the dropdown "shop", you cannot click on the subnav's that sit above the jquery slider. Rather than re-coding, is there a quick CSS fix?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue 2:**

You need to set your z-index stacks so that the header is above the main content area

```
#header { position: relative; z-index: 2; }
#content-wrapper {position: relative; z-index:1; }
```

**Issue 1:**

Just check adding a space between 'IE' and '8' like so:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>< ![endif]-->
```

Comment: Thanks lnrbob - figured out issue two was due to a 2em margin where hovering over that space made it disappear! I'll try adding the space for issue one. Will revert shortly thanks!!

Comment: On the mac now at home so I can't check it in IE :(

Comment: sorry, got distracted talking about kindles... Looks good to me! Using IE9 in IE8 and IE7 mode menus work and the conditional comment stays in the head :)

Comment: No worries, glad it helped. Check it for yourself when you can just to be safe! Especially nice to help out on a .co.za, makes me all nostalgic!

Comment: Thank you lnrbob. Checked it out and it's working beautifully! :)